# PHP DOMDocument - InsertBefore multiple times

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am a situation where I'd like to add the same content in several locations in an XML file. FYI - first time tackling DOMDocument. 
Say the xml looks like

```
<rrd>
  <rra>
    <cdp_prep>
      <ds>
        <value>nan</value>
      </ds>
      <ds>
        <value>nan</value>
      </ds>
      <ds>
        <value>nan</value>
      <ds>
     </cdp_prep>
     <database>
        ...
     </database>
   </rra>
  <rra>
    <cdp_prep>
      <ds>
        <value>nan</value>
      <ds>
      </ds>
        <value>nan</value>
      <ds>
      <ds>
        <value>nan</value>
      </ds>
     </cdp_prep>
     <database>
        ...
     </database>
   </rra>
</rrd>
```

If i use something like `$rrdCDPds = $xRRD->query("/rrd/rra/cdp_prep/ds");` then i would get all the `<ds>` elements. In this case i would have a length of 6. However, I'm trying to insertBefore on the second `<ds>` of each `<cdp_prep>` element. My issue is if i query on "/rrd/rra/cdp_prep", how do i target the insertBefore on the 2nd `<ds>` element for every `<cdp_prep>` element?

Comment: The xml is not valid .. did you mean to close the `ds` elements?

Comment: yes sorry. friday afternoon... and beating head on keyboard :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic procedure is:

1. Select the nodes you want to use as `insertBefore` reference nodes. You can get this using the child axis and a position test: `cdp_prep/child::ds[position()=2]`, which can be abbreviated as `cdp_prep/ds[2]`.
2. Prepare the nodes you want to insert.
3. For each matching reference node, clone the node you want to insert and then insert it.

Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$newcontent = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$newcontent->appendChild($dom->createElement('NEWCONTENT'));
$newcontent->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("\n      "));

$DSs = $xp->query('/rrd/rra/cdp_prep/ds[2]');

foreach ($DSs as $ds) {
    $ds->parentNode->insertBefore($newcontent->cloneNode(true), $ds);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `child` axis in XPath to select the second ds child:

```
/rrd/rra/cdp_prep/child::ds[2]
```